# angularjs template variable not working on a server

Tags: angularjs, django, nginx, django-templates, uwsgi

I am facing a strange issue which has killed my hours but not able to debug the failure exactly.

Angularjs template variable is not displaying its value from  my server on UI. Not sure where I am missing (which I think I am not).

Exactly same piece of code is working perfectly fine on plunkr or anywhere else.

My project a django project, and I have tried restarting nginx and uwsgi but no suuccess. Can anyone please help me here.

Please let me know if you need any fuurther information.

Here is my plunkr which is perfectly fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/bSmRh90sIODc0zksx7Ow?p=preview

```
      <body ng-app="scopeExample">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
  {{username}}
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

One more point here to add is under source tab, I don't see the template variable. All other fields are shown but the template variable {{username}} is not even showing.

Comment: any error there in console?

Comment: No..console is not showing any error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with the help of my teammate. The reason for this issue is Django and angular uses same syntax for template variable. So when DJango sends the page, it searches for all variable with {{}} braces and replaces it with the django view variable.

In our case, django doesn't understand the variable defined in angular and replaces it with blank.

SO here are to solutions for this. To use the angular variable in template we need to sue verbatim block. Django will not replace anything under this block.

Syntax is: `{% verbatim %}jj{{usernameOne}} {% endverbatim %}`

All variable in verbatim block will be treated as angular variable.